# Not getting Data on update of link in Vue and Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

Can someone please tell me how can I update the data on getting the id from url.

Like this

I have a sidebar having some categories. category 1, category2, 
link on category1 and category 2 is category/1 and category/2

on loading the page I am getting the data from category1 but when I click on category 2, page is not updating the content.

Can anyone please tell me how can we do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can you `vue-router` https://router.vuejs.org/ 
Register your routes like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import App from "@/views/App.vue"
import Category from "@/views/Category.vue"

Vue.use(Router);

const routes = [{
    name: "category",
    path: "/category/:id",
    component: Category
}];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

some where in your root template, aka App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div> 
    <nav> 
      <router-link to="{ name: 'category', params: {id: 1} }">category 1</router-link>
      <router-link to="{ name: 'category', params: {id: 2} }">category 2</router-link>
     </nav>
     <main>
       <router-view></router-view>
     </main>
  </div>
</template>
```

and in Category.vue you must watch to the $route, because when chanaged :id param in route, vue-router dose'nt rerender component as designed.

```
<template>
  <div>
     {{ category }}
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data: { category: "" },
  watch: {
    "$route": (to, from) => {
      this.category = to.params.id;
    }
  },
  created: () => {
    this.category = this.$route.params.id;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming your content is in the router-view: use router-link and point to the corresponding path assinged in your vue-router instance

First page oft the documentation:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html